# MySQL: Is there a way to update a field so that all foreign key related fields are updated as well?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, update

I'm assuming the answer to this question is yes but it is hard to Google this type of question and not get overly ambiguous results.

I am working with a database that was dumped from a Magento instance - EAV architecture. It stores orders with the column entity_id and uses this field throughout the DB, something close to 20 tables by my count. Magento uses foreign keys on this entity_id column to keep track of its relationship to other tables.

My Question: Is there any way to run an update query so that the MySQL DB will automatically update every foreign key related column in the database? I need to "shift" about 1000 of these incremental entity IDs in order to successful merge orders from another Magento instance. Thank you.

Example of update: Change entity_id from 9567 to 10567.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update the multiple tables interlinked with foreign keys. The constraints in MySQL only updates the related column.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see. Well is there any way to model foreign key constraints across a database to get a better idea of how they are inter-related?